# android dropbox image upload file Fileinputstream

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am working on an Android app which I took from the picture gallery and upload to the Dropbox.My problem is that the fileinputstream can not find the file.
Please help code will be below, and also the log messages

```
public class UplodeFileToDropBox extends AsyncTask<Void , Void ,Boolean>{
private  Context context ;
private  DropboxAPI dropboxAPI ;
private  File imagefile ;
private  String dropboxpath ;



public UplodeFileToDropBox(Context context, DropboxAPI dropboxAPI, String dropboxpath, File imagefile)
{
     super();
     this.context = context ;
     this.dropboxAPI = dropboxAPI ;
     this.dropboxpath = dropboxpath ;
     this.imagefile = imagefile ;

}


@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    try
    {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(imagefile);

        Log.i("DbExampleLog", inputStream.toString());

        dropboxAPI.putFile(dropboxpath, inputStream, imagefile.length(), null, null);
        return true ;
    }
    catch (DropboxException e)
    {
        Log.i("DbexEpshon",e.getMessage() );
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.i("DbExampleLog", e.getMessage());
    }

    return  false ;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if (result)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "File has been upLoded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context , "Error wile loding" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while uploading.");
    }
}
```

}

log messages

```
10-19 10:51:32.395  22850-23233/com.example.pige.dorpin I/DbExampleLog﹕ /external/images/media/31
```

10-19 10:51:32.395  22850-23233/com.example.pige.dorpin I/DbExampleLog﹕ /external/images/media/31: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-19 10:51:32.398  22850-23233/com.example.pige.dorpin I/DbExampleLog﹕ The uploaded file's rev is:

Comment: It looks like you're adding a ".jpeg" to the end of the file path, but that's not where the actual file is?

Comment: hi even withe the .jpeg removed it still dunes open a fileinputstream

Comment: Well, start simplifying your code. You also seem to be concatenating a string and a file... I'm not sure why that would even work. If you can simplify your code to a dozen lines or so (just trying to open the file), it may be easier for you to spot the error.

Comment: thanks ill give it a try

Comment: can you have a look i have cleaned my code

Comment: What line is causing the exception? Where does `imagefile` come from, and how do you know it's a valid file? (The error indicates there's no file at that path.)

Comment: I'm guessing it's the `InputFileStream` constructor that's causing the exception, and it's because you're passing in a `File` object that points to a path that doesn't exist (or otherwise can't be read).

Comment: thank you for all you help  but i figured it out